# get masked value from input box when using Robin Herbots' Inputmask

Tags: javascript, cypress, input-mask

We use Robin Herbot's Inputmask to mask input values for our js form input boxes (150000 => "$ 150,000" for dollar inputs, 052439876 => "052-43-9876" for SSN inputs, etc.).

An example of a mask we add to an input element is:

```
{
  name: 'numeric',
  attributes: {
      prefix: '$ ',
      radixPoint: '.',
      autoGroup: true,
      groupSeparator: ',',
      autoUnmask: true,
      clearMaskOnLostFocus: true,
      showMaskOnFocus: false,
      showMaskOnHover: false,
      oncleared: ev => {
          ev.target.value = null;
          ev.target.placeholder = '';
      }
  }
}
```

I'm using Cypress to automate testing and I'm trying to validate that a value such as 150000 is, in fact, displaying as "$ 150,000". However, I cannot seem to "grab" the masked value (as it is displayed), only the unmasked value of 150000. Any suggestions as to how I can grab the displayed value of "$ 150,000"?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the dom(HTML) structure of the web element which has the masked value?

Comment: @AlapanDas - Using dev tools->inspect element I get

<input class="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-1 px-2 text-gray-600 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" placeholder="" im-insert="true" style="text-align: right;">

Comment: You should be able to `cy.get('input').should('have.value', '$ 150,000')`. What does "grab" look like in your test?

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker means simply get the text that is displayed in the input box. So in my example, the value of the input element is 150000, NOT '$ 150,000'. So, `cy.get('input').should('have.value', 150000)` returns success, but `cy.get('input').should('have.value', '$ 150,000)'` yields fail, as does `cy.get('input').should('have.text', '$ 150,000')`

Comment: Cheers, so clearly you get a different result to me. How do you apply the mask object shown, I'd like to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker In this case, we define the <input> element and apply various css classes (e.g. 'appearance-none border rounded w-full py-1 px-2 text-gray-600 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline'), set the value (0 by default), and then apply the mask to the element with something like:

`new Inputmask(this.mask.name, this.mask.attributes).mask(input);`

where:

`input = the input element object`
`this.mask.name = the name of a predefined mask (e.g. 'numeric')`

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker (cont'd)

`this.mask.attributes = (in this case) the following list of attributes:`

`{
    prefix: '$ ',
    radixPoint: '.',
    autoGroup: true,
    groupSeparator: ',',
    autoUnmask: true,
    clearMaskOnLostFocus: true,
    showMaskOnFocus: false,
    showMaskOnHover: false,
    oncleared: ev => {
        ev.target.value = null;
        ev.target.placeholder = '';
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are getting the value.

Using the [demo page](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/), this works ok

```js
it('gets masked value', () => {

  cy.visit('https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/')

  cy.contains('Demo').click()

  cy.get("[data-inputmask=\"'alias': 'numeric', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': false, 'prefix': '$ ', 'placeholder': '0'\"]")
    .type('150000')
    .should('have.value', '$ 150,000.00');

})
```

Comment: Yes. That's correct, because the actual value is set as the masked text of '$ 150,000'. If you add the following after the .should:

`.invoke('val')
 .then(($value) => {
 let iVal = $value
 cy.log(iVal);
 })`

you will see the value of '$ 150,000' get logged. However, in our case the actual value is 150000, but is DISPLAYED in the text  box as '$ 150,000'. I want to verify that the text is properly being displayed (masked) given the entered value.

Comment: I don't think there's an internal "raw" value and an "displayed" value - my impression is the plugin just modifies the text as it's entered, using a keypress handler.